# Spring Security is not preventing unauthorized users to login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to learn Spring and I've set up Spring Security in my application. I'd simply would like to allow access only to users who are in the database, using my Login page that has a simple form and that should be in https, but at the moment https is not enforced by Spring although it should, and anyone can "login" in my application and receive no error after they use the login page.

This is my SecurityConfig.java page:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
    throws Exception {
    auth
    .jdbcAuthentication()
    .dataSource(dataSource)
    .usersByUsernameQuery(
            "select username, password" +
            "from users where username=?")
    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
    "select username from users where username=?")
    .passwordEncoder(new StandardPasswordEncoder("53cr3t"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/Login.html")
        .and()
        .logout()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/Login").authenticated().
        anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .requiresChannel()
        .antMatchers("/Login").requiresSecure();
    }
}
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MusicPortal</display-name>
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
</filter-class>
</filter>



</web-app>
```

And this is my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.loucat.musicportal.controller,com.loucat.musicportal.model,com.loucat.musicportal.dao"/>


<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver" p:templateEngine-ref="templateEngine"/>
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine" p:templateResolver-ref="templateResolver" />
<bean id="templateResolver"
      class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
  <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
</bean> 



<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/musicportal" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="postgres" />
    </bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />


</beans>
```

My Login page is Login.html and it has a form that post the results to /PostLogin.html, which has another Controller.
I wonder if this may be a problem, as in some tutorial I've seen they re-suse the Login page itself.

I hope this is enough to get some help, thanks!

Comment: What is the package of SecurityConfig? Is it listed in spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml?

Comment: I think this is the problem: anyRequest().authenticated()

Comment: @chomnoue: the package wasn't listed, thanks for spotting this. But the behavour doesn't change after adding it...

Comment: @StimpsonCat : why do you think it's a problem? I'm asking that any request is authenticated, but none is... am I using it in the wrong way?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

to your spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: I did but nothing changes.

Comment: Not sure if it worth mentioning... my form (Login.html) has a post method that goes into a page called PostLogin.html, which is mapped to a controller method. 
Is this the correct way to do it also for an authorized login form?